# pandas rolling(n).corr() stuck on 1 no matter what the data is?

Tags: pandas

No matter what data I put in I only get back coefficients of 1 as a return.

```
data = {"one":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
compute = data["one"].rolling(3).corr()

0    NaN
1    NaN
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    1.0
```

I am trying to get it to give me the rolling correlation however the return I am getting would indicate that I do not understand whats going on here or I am doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: This is not reproducible.  You have different variables `d` and `data`.  If you change `data` to `d` you get: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rolling'`

Comment: Also, that's not how you use `corr()`.  That would raise: `TypeError: corr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'`

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 - there is a line missing `data = pd.DataFrame(d)` then it's reproducible. You can compute the correlation of one column without an error, but it is always `1.0` (correlation with itself). You don't need 'other'. And this is exactly why every row is `1.0`.

Comment: @carlwalters - I think you need to explain what you expect as output. Most likely you need another approach. @C8H10N4O2 is right: That's not how one would usually use `corr`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I edited d to data.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Thank you, so basically its correlate the 1 column with its self so in order to get numbers other than 1 I need to correlate with this another column?

Comment: yeah it looks like you can only get 1 and NaN by doing this.  Either the correlation is perfect or undefined (try a series of all the same value).  interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but `foo.rolling(n).corr()` where `foo` is a linear sequence gives you the correlation of a linear sequence and its shifted self (so equal rate of increase), so the correlation is by definition 1.  See for yourself:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {"one":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
data=pd.DataFrame(d)
compute = data["one"].rolling(3).corr()
for i in data["one"].rolling(3):
    print(i)
```

returns:

```
Name: one, dtype: int64
0    1
1    2
Name: one, dtype: int64
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: one, dtype: int64
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: one, dtype: int64
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: one, dtype: int64
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: one, dtype: int64
4    5
5    6
6    7
Name: one, dtype: int64
5    6
6    7
7    8
Name: one, dtype: int64
```